# Limiting number of nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am querying a Neo4j database that stores building floorpans. An example of a query is:

```
MATCH (s:STOREYVERTEX) <-- (room0: LIVING) 
MATCH (s) <-- (room1: DINING) 
MATCH (s) <-- (room2: KITCHEN) 
MATCH (room0) - [edge0: DOOR] -> (room2) 
MATCH (room2) - [edge1: DOOR] -> (room1) 
RETURN s
```

Now this returns all graphs that have a subgraph corresponding to the constraints. I would like to somehow limit the number of nodes that the result graph have, so for the given example I would like to get only the graphs that have exactly 3 nodes, all of type ROOM.

Is there a way to do this in Cypher?

Edit:
Something like this does not work:

```
MATCH (s:STOREYVERTEX) <-- (rooms:ROOM) 
WITH s, count(distinct(rooms)) as numberOfRooms
WHERE numberOfRooms = 3
MATCH (s) <-- (room1: DINING) 
MATCH (s) <-- (room2: KITCHEN) 
MATCH (room0) - [edge0: DOOR] -> (room2) 
MATCH (room2) - [edge1: DOOR] -> (room1) 
RETURN s
```

Comment: please try to use semantically meaningful relationship-types in your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What finally solved my problem was:

```
MATCH (s:STOREYVERTEX) <-- (rooms) 
WITH s, count(distinct(rooms)) as numberOfRooms
WHERE numberOfRooms = 3
MATCH (s) <-- (room1: KITCHEN) 
MATCH (s) <-- (room2: DINING)
RETURN s
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do that, like this:

```
MATCH (s:STOREYVERTEX) <-- (rooms:ROOM) 
WITH s, count(distinct(rooms)) as numberOfRooms
WHERE numberOfRooms = 3
RETURN s;
```

This just checks how many distinct different rooms are connected to a `STOREYVERTEX`, and only returns the `s` values where that's 3.

You didn't specify what the `DOOR` stuff was about in your query, but you should be able to modify this query from here to get where you want to go.

Comment: Yeah, I just copied the whole query from my app, but in this particular question DOOR is not really relevant. Thanks a bunch! :)

Comment: Hmm, on second thought, I'm not sure this is a solution for me. Not all nodes are ROOMs. I edited the query a bit in the question - is it still possible in such a query to constraint the results to only graph with 3 nodes, whatever their type?

Comment: Just remove the ROOM label.

Comment: I edited the question again, to show you what I actually want. The given query does not work, but that's the direction I wanna go in. I'm sorry if I don't manage to ask the correct question, I'm very new to Cypher.

Answer (score 1):

First you could label all rooms as, well, ROOM.
So when you create a new, for example, kitchen node you would label it both KITCHEN and ROOM:

```
CREATE (a:KITCHEN:ROOM {...})
```

For now you can add the labels to the existing nodes like this:

```
MATCH (room:Kitchen) SET room :ROOM return room
```

Congratz, now all your kitchen nodes are also room nodes!

This allows you to treat that node as a kitchen, when you need kitchens, or as a general room, when you need those.
If you do that for relevant all nodes (Living, Dining,...) you could then do something like:

```
    MATCH (s:STOREYVERTEX)-[r]-(room: ROOM)
    WITH s, count(r) as rel_count
    WHERE rel_count = 3
    RETURN s
```

This will return the nodes 's' with 3 relationships (no matter what the rel type is) to any node with the label ROOM.